# predicate identification

Tags: subjects, parsing, predicate

What are the subject and predicate of the following sentence? Is it grammatically correct? If not, how would you fix it?

> The Castle Fire ignited in August when dry brush sparked by a lightning storm ultimately spread to join other fires and form the enormous, 174,000-acre Sequoia Lightning Complex Fire.

Answer (score 0):

The subject is "The Castle Fire", the predicate is the rest of the sentence.

It gets a bit confused as it literally says that the "dry brush spread"  I'm happy to interpret this as "the fire that started in the dry brush spread..." because I don't think the actual brush can spread.

For clarity it might be better to split the sentence:

> The Castle Fire started in August when the dry brush was sparked by a lightning storm.  It ultimately spread to join other fires and form the enormous, 174,000-acre, Sequoia Lightning Complex Fire.

Comment: The "It" in your second sentence refers to the Castle Fire, so your version makes more sense than the CNN original.

Comment: "Ignited in August when dry brush [was] sparked by a lightning storm" could be read as a separate phrase describing the fire, if separated by commas and the verb added.

Comment: I find CNN's English getting worse and worse.

Comment: If it's from CNN, you should mention that in the question.

Comment: @KateBunting but that sort of omission is not something desirable. And might be considered incorrect, I guess.

Comment: @Man_From_India Oh, no, I didn't intend to suggest that it was desirable. I was just trying to make sense of the sentence.