# Can I use "competing" in place of "competition" in this sentence?

Tags: nouns, gerunds

I would like to ask a question about a gerund and a noun.

Here is the phrase in a passage about history:
(1)Always in danger of **competition** from neighbouring Spain, the Portuguese began subcontracting their spice distribution to Dutch traders.

I am wondering if it is correct to use Ving **(competing)** instead a noun **(competition)**.
(2)Always in danger of **competing** from neighbouring Spain, the Portuguese began subcontracting their spice distribution to Dutch traders.

I think that 1st sentence emphasizes on a whole completed action in the past.
2nd sentence emphasizes on the action which was in process in the past. Is this correct?

Comment: You need the noun "competition". The verb "competing" would be ungrammatical -- we cannot "compete from something".

Comment: @BillJ want to direct your attention to this question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/294748/3463 (notice "sparkled", I am confused there.) Can you help there?

Comment: @Man_From_India I don't follow you. It actually says "sparked", not "sparkled".

Comment: @BillJ sorry my mistake. Yes "sparked" but is that part correct without the omission of "was" before that?

Comment: @BillJ I understand but then it would turn like this: "when NP, something happened". Is it correct?

Comment: @Man_From_India Let me check the original text to be sure about the interpretation and syntax.

Comment: @Bill What if I write
My competing with other rivals to get a gold medal makes me tired

Is this correct?

Comment: @Man_From_India Looking at the original text, it seems that “sparked by a lightning storm” is in fact an adjunct (of cause) in clause structure, not a modifier in NP structure.

Comment: @BillJ still in that case, it would seem like the bush spread, which is not right I guess

Comment: @Man_From_India It was the lightning storm that caused the dry bush to join forces and form the enormous fire.

Comment: @BillJ then what about the The Castle Fire? I mean what is the verb that this Castle Fire agrees with?

Comment: @Man_From_India It's an adjunct in the VP "ultimately spread to join other fires ... ".

Comment: @BillJ so it is essentially like this: [[The Castle Fire] [ignited in August when dry brush sparked by a lightning storm ultimately spread to join other fires and form the enormous, 174,000-acre Sequoia Lightning Complex Fire].

Comment: Always in danger of competing with etc. but it would mean something different.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/competition), **competition** describes "a situation in which someone is trying to win something or be more successful than someone else".

The keyword there is **situation**: by contrast, gerunds describe an **activity**, for example:

> I like swimming

In your sentence, you are talking about a situation, not an activity, so **competition** is the only word that works.

Comment: What if I write My competing with other rivals to get a gold medal makes me tired.
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is a correct usage of the gerund.

Comment: thanks so much for verifying